# ASP.NET authorization won't recognize JWT bearer in SignalR CONNECT request

Tags: asp.net, authorization, signalr

Users of my libs, that handle authorization for ASP.NET web APIs (JWT bearer assertion), now wants to use SignalR. I read up on SignalR authorization and, according to Microsoft's documentation it should work out of the box, but I can't see that it does.

I use the `IConfigureNamedOptions` approach and simply supplies a `JwtBearerOptions` object that also listens to the events. In the `OnMessageReceived` event I ensure a token passed in the query string ("`acccess_token`") is honored and, if so, assigns it to the `MessageReceivedContext.Token` property.

This works like a charm in every other scenario, but for the SignalR CONNECT request it seems the token is not recognized for some reason, and I end up with a challenge.

Has anyone seen this? I don't understand why the SignalR CONNECT request would be handled differently but maybe there's a good reason?

Comment: Please share your signalr client code and your Program.cs about `OnMessageReceived` .  And please hide your sensitive info.